# HTML+JQuery Equalizer Bars aligned to bottom / middle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, equalizer

I'm trying to build a very simple HTML/JQuery Equalizer.
The Problem I can't fix is, to align the bars to the bottom and expand to the top.

Here's my Code:

```js
window.setInterval(function(){
  $('.eqitem').each(function(){
    $(this).height(Math.floor(Math.random() * 250) + 50 );
  });
}, 500);
```

```css
.parent{
    height: 300px;
}

.eqitem{
    float: left;
    height: 0px;
    width: 10px;
    background: darkred;
    margin-right: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.5s ease-out;
    transition: height 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <div id="eq">
        <div class="eqitem"></div>
        <div class="eqitem"></div>
        <div class="eqitem"></div>
        <div class="eqitem"></div>
        <div class="eqitem"></div>                    
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried vertical-align, absolute and relative positioning, bottom attribute, ...
Nothing of the above seems to work or even causes unwanted problems.

Thank you guys so much for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to mix relative and absolute positioning to position items at the bottom of a relatively positioned container.

To achieve what you want, you need something like this js:

```
var offset_width = 15;
var i = 0;
$('.eqitem').each(function(){
    $(this).css('left', (i*offset_width) + 'px');
  i++;
});
```

and this css:

```
   #eq {
      position:relative;
    display: block;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100px;
     }
    .eqitem{
        position:absolute;
        height: 0px;
        width: 10px;
        background: darkred;
        margin-right: 5px;
        -webkit-transition: height 0.5s ease-out;
        transition: height 0.5s ease-out;
        display:inline-block;

        bottom:0;
    }
```

Please have a look at the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/catbadger/pzy15m8e/1/

Comment: Thank you so much! 
It works perfectly now. I almost had this solution, but the "float: left" possibly destroyed it.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this in a simple and elegant way using the following -

```
#eq{
  display : flex;
  height: 300px;
}

.eqitem{
   display: inline-block;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

Checkout the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/faza746j/1/)
Checkout the [Browser Compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Comment: While this works if every one of your users is using the latest browsers, it doesn't work in all of the browsers I need to support... https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp

Comment: Yup. That's why the link to Browser Compatibility in the answer to check if anyone facing a similar problem is fine with it. Although, I would say 97.19% is a pretty good coverage!